# I get error: C2501 on declaration of strings

Tags: c++, string

```
#ifndef vid
#define vid
#include<cstring>
#include<string>
#include<string.h>


class Video
{
protected:
 string title;
 int id;
 string genre;
 string type;
 string actor;
 bool available;


public :
 virtual double rent();
 virtual void displayDetails();

};


#endif
```

I get this error on declaration of all string attributes.

> error C2501: 'string' : missing storage-class or type specifiers
>   Please help

Comment: Why are you including every possible string header? The only one you need in this case is `string`

Comment: @Praetorian: he was probably experimenting to get the string recognized properly, and left it in there before posting. I would not make a fuss about it.

Comment: @LaszloPapp Umm, `string.h` and `cstring` are inherited from the C standard library and will never fix any problems with `std::string`. And how is pointing out something dubious to a beginner *fussing*? If anyone's being fussy, it's you whining about the *merits* of mentioning adding `using namespace std;` *in a header* to a beginner.

Comment: I do not understand your post. When someone is a beginner, that person will try everything to solve the issues, including header files. You are not pointing at anything new btw because I already did that in my reply, and yes typing "std" many times when _unneeded_ is uncomfortable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`string` is defined under `std` name space, you could fix your code by providing full namespace:

```
std::string genre;
std::string type;
std::string actor;
```

Comment: I think this is a bad suggestion without providing alternatives with pro/cons. If there is no namespace clash, I do not think anyone would like to type this much.

Answer (score 0):

`string` is included in namespace `std`.

So either qualify the identifier directly as:

```
std::string
```

Or use `using` directive(which should not be preferred for such limited use)

```
using namespace std;
string str;
```

Or use a `using` declaration

```
using std::string;
string str;
```

Comment: I don't think the second option is a good idea. Newcomers should not be encouraged to use that. Bear in mind that this is a header file.

Comment: @juanchopanza if you read properly, I have already written that. Is that the downvote for?

Comment: Yeah, the file in question is a header, so even mentioning `using namespace std` is a bad idea. OP might decide to go with that and break their or someone else's code.

Comment: Saksham: fwiw, I disagree with juan. I think it is good to mention all the possibilities with its pro/cons, and that is I personally did after his comment for my reply.

Comment: @LaszloPapp yes. Thanks!. seems juan is on a spree of downvoting every answer.

Comment: Saksham: that is fine as he is entitled to. What I dislike personally is that when someone applies his suggestion, he keeps the downvoting there. That is not fair.